# Align ASP.NET Texbox Controls

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I am a begginer with ASP.NET programming.
I have 3 Textbox controls and 3 label words before the textboxes:

Name/Company:[TextBox1]
Email:[TextBox2]
Message:[TextBox3]

I want to align the textboxes on top of each other. I also want the labels/words to align left of the textboxes. Like shown below:

```
Name/Company:[TextBox1]

       Email:[TextBox2]

     Message:[TextBox3          ]

             [                  ]

             [                  ]

             [                  ]

             [                  ]
```

Currently my messsage label is at the last line of the textbox3 control and my other controls aren't positioned right. What my output is now:

```
Name/Company:[TextBox1]

Email:[TextBox2]

        [TextBox3          ]

        [                  ]

        [                  ]

        [                  ]

Message:[                  ]
```

code:

```
<p>
    Name/Company:
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</p>
<p>
    Email:<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</p>
<p>
    Message:
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Height="100px" Width="300px"></asp:TextBox>
</p>
```

I been working with java programming for a few years. On that I used to create section JPanels and add buttons,textfields and layouts on them to get the positioning right. Is there a similar way of doing it with ASP.NET? If not, what other ways can I achieve this layout and positioning?

Thanks

Comment: Are you familiar with CSS?

Comment: Yes. Only a bit though.

Comment: Find a tutorial and start from there. See some videos, read some books...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like this, and use `display: table`

```css
.tbl {
  display: table;
}
.tbl > div {
  display: table-row;
}
.tbl > div > * {
  display: table-cell;
}
.tbl > div > span {
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tbl">
  <div>
    <span>Name/Company:</span>
    <input type="text" ID="TextBox1">
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Email:</span>
    <input type="text" ID="TextBox2">
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Message:</span>
    <input type="text" ID="TextBox3">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. CSS is the way to go!

Answer (score 0):

Declare classes in css and make `<div>` to align your items:

```
<head>
<style>
  .cls1{
   float:left;
   width:10%;
   margin:5px;
  }
  .cls2{
   float:left;
   text-align:left;
   width:79%;
   margin:5px;
  }
</style>
</head>


  <div class="cls1">
  Name/Company: 
  </div>
  <div class="cls2">
  <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
  </div>
  <div class="cls1">
  Email: 
  </div>
  <div class="cls2">
  <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
  </div>
  <div class="cls1">
  Message: 
  </div>
  <div class="cls2">
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Height="100px" Width="300px"></asp:TextBox>
  </div>
```